Ubuntu 24.04 LTS network bridge
I got some problem when bridging in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
When I use this config:
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
        eth1:
            addresses: [ 192.168.1.2/24 ]
        eth2: {}
        eth3:
            addresses: [ 192.168.2.2/24 ]
        eth4:
            addresses: [ 192.168.4.2/24 ]

the interface worked perfectly. But when I change it into:
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
        eth1:
            dhcp4: false
        eth2: {}
        eth3:
            addresses: [ 192.168.2.2/24 ]
        eth4:
            addresses: [ 192.168.4.2/24 ]
    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces: [ eth1 ]
            addresses: [ 192.168.1.2/24 ]
            parameters:
                stp: true
                forward-delay: 4
            macaddress: 00:15:5d:83:06:01

the br0 stopped working. I need to bridge eth1 and eth2 interface, and I only put one interface as slave for testing.
What did I miss?

I've a working bridged setup on 22.04, and I don't think it will be very different
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
      match:
          macaddress: AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
      set-name: wan
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
      ignore-carrier: true
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
      ignore-carrier: true
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
      ignore-carrier: true

  bridges:
    lan:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
       - 192.168.2.1/24
      interfaces:
        - enp2s0
        - enp3s0
        - enp4s0

Couple of specific things I've done

I use match since in some more advanced setups I name the ports

For the 'main'/Wan port I've used mac address matching and set-name so I know which port is which. In another set up I did, I have a mix of port speeds, so having them labelled both internally and physically is very handy. This is also an easy way to not have the "predictable" network names.
For each port on the bridge
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
      ignore-carrier: true

I think I got the dhcp: no from the netplan docs. Optional and ignore-carrier are cause of delays at boot time if a port isn't used.
I believe the bridging  block changed at some point. I don't have an older set of config (I just ran the classic network /etc/networks)
  bridges:
    lan:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
       - 192.168.2.1/24
      interfaces:
        - enp2s0
        - enp3s0
        - enp4s0

Your bridge probably shouldn't/wouldn't have a mac address assigned to it
An educated guess would suggest your bridges block would look something like this
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
       - 192.168.2.1/24
      interfaces:
        - eth1
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4

sudo netplan try should advice you of any issues IIRC  but I think this should work.

Okay.. it didn't work either. I added mac address because it didn't work. I've also put match in ethernets and set-name, but I thought it was only cosmetical, so when it failed, I reformatted the VM, and reinstall everything, and tried your suggestion. But it still didn't work. I installed opnsense just to try the system, and it worked.
